# I cannot run Earth – Multivariate adaptive regression splines in orange

Tags: python-3.x, orange

I installed orange with

```
pip install orange3
```

When I run

```
from Orange.regression import earth
```

it says

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'earth'
```

Similarly, when I try

```
c = Orange.regression.earth.EarthLearner(data, degree=2, terms=10)
```

It says

```
AttributeError: module 'Orange.regression' has no attribute 'earth'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EarthLearner was an add-on (`orangecontrib.earth` pypi package) for orange (v2) and is not available for orange3.